# Padrão de URL em RESTful service

Tags: c#, rest, restful, wcf

Estou desenvolvendo um serviço que irá disponibilizar algumas funções para acesso externo, usando arquitetura REST. É o início de uma RestAPI para a empresa.
Mas vamos ao problema. Preciso atualizar alguns dados pontuais de um determinado produto. Então decidi utilizar como padrão para a URL:

```
http://..../Produtos/{id}/ValorVenda/{valor}
```

No caso acima, o campo *valor* se refere ao novo valor do produto.
Entretanto, não gostaria de fazer essa transação utilizando o método GET.
Então pensei em adotar este padrão para URL:

```
http://..../Produtos/{id}
```

Gostaria de utilizar o método POST e passar os novos dados do produto através de um JSON.
Na pesquisa que realizei não encontrei nada parecido, então também não tenho certeza se é a maneira correta de fazer.

Comment: Para alterações parciais é mais interessante utilizar o método **`PATCH`**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depende, o POST seria o método mais adequado para inserção e não para atualização.

A ideia de um serviço REST é utilizar os métodos para cada situação de acordo com o que eles oferecem.

Os métodos básicos se assemelham com um CRUD:

- GET: READ
- POST: CREATE
- PUT: UPDATE
- DELETE: DELETE

No caso, o que você teria de usar para ser do jeito "mais correto" seria o PUT e não o POST se você fosse atualizar um valor já existente, porém se você não tiver o valor e tiver de inserir um novo, então o POST seria o mais adequado, mas isso vai da sua arquitetura de dados.

Desta forma você poderia mandar uma informação através do Body deste método para uma URL do tipo `http://www.suaurl.com.br/Produtos/{id}` e capturar a requisição do outro lado.

Estes links podem te ajudar:

- http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp
- http://gc.blog.br/2007/07/02/post-vs-put-quem-insere-e-quem-altera/
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107390/whats-the-difference-between-a-post-and-a-put-http-request
- http://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/put-vs-post/